# Usage of car burglar alarm system to send sms with GSM unit and arduino

Tags: arduino, automotive, gsm

My vehicle have a car burglar alarm system. I want to setup **Arduino Nano or Micro Module** with **SIM800L GPRS GSM Module** to get **SMS** when alarm raised.

**I want to clarify these things.**

- I think easiest way to get the alarm fired signal from **car alarm speaker**. (If not please suggest best method for do it and ignore bellow diagram.)

How to used this scenario as a input for GSM module.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGdi3p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is an *after-market* alarm, not factory, right? Note that aftermarket alarms have their own wire for signaling an alarm trip, at least all the ones that I've seen. That being said, the speaker should work, as long as the speaker ONLY activates when an alarm actually occurs...Some alarms will chirp if the battery in the key fob get low. Perhaps you could have the microcontroller determine the duration of the signal on the speaker.

Comment: You do realize that SM will not alert you that the car is in the process of being stolen, only that it has already been stolen, perhaps many hours ago? Add a GPS system that SMS's the location periodically and it might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The output from the speaker is going to most likely be a relatively high frequency square wave, it is not a good idea to use this to power or enable a module directly.

Use the arduino! Feed the output of the speaker to the arduino, make sure the voltage levels are within what the arduino pin tolerates, if not condition the signal with a simple resistor network.

Now apply some software magic: Whenever the arduino detects the speaker signal it simply causes the GSM module to transmit.

Comment: What happen when I used relay and connect relay output to arduino as input and trigger sms using that relay signal?

Comment: @devopsEMK - If I understand you correctly, you're asking about using the speaker to activate a relay? That won't work, as a relay needs a specific constant DC voltage and current, while an audio signal is nothing like that.

Comment: Here is the deal: You need to somehow trigger a SMS TX using the output of the speaker. The output of a speaker, as i said, is a square wave it cannot drive the module directly in anyway. But you have a microprocessor in your hands! So program the arduino so that when it detects a pulse (or even a single change ) on the speaker wire, it makes the module transmit.Why use a realy when this method has no additional part cost?

Comment: This is I can use sound sensor to get the value from alarm speaker because that speaker in under the bonet. So when I push the horn button that sound also identify.

Comment: Sorry i dont quite understand your comment. Where did the sound sensor come from?

Comment: Sorry sound sensor is work around solution.But it's not adapt for this project.